# Multiple reads interupted by alarm

Tags: c, serial-port

I have set multiple blocking reads on a serial port and doing timeout by using setitimer(). When I finish reading (or the timeout expires and read() returns EINT) I write a different message, restart alarm and start to read again. However, I have now encountred a problem - what can I do when the alarm expires right between two reads? I would like to stop now, but I would just go to that next read. (seting some flag would just change the question to "What should I do, if the alarm expires between the flag and read?")

Comment: Where's the code? We need to see an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What does the alarm mean? Does it mean something's wrong? If so, don't you have to deal with the failure?

Comment: "doing timeout by using setitimer()". There's a better way to implement timeout. Use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to wait for input to become available. `select` has built in timeout support.

Comment: @david I have multiple devices I have to comunicate with and I need to quickly comunicate with (switch between) all of them.

Comment: @kaylum no, I can't use select, read the question again please

Comment: @Charlestone The question doesn't explain why you can't use `select`. It seems like you definitely *should* use `select`.

Comment: "I have set *multiple* blocking reads" - I need to set up the timeout for all of them as a whole, not separetely. E.g. If I wanted to wait for 5s and used `select()` for two reads, it might happen that the first read() (the select() before first read) would block for 4 second and than the second `read()` would block for another 5 second - 9 second all together. But I wanted to wait for just 5 seconds.

Comment: @Charlestone When you use `select`, you also set all your descriptors non-blocking. You never block at all. You decide how long you are willing to wait and pass that to `select`.

Comment: sorry, i thought I was clear. E.g. If I wanted to wait for 5s and used select() for two reads, it might happen that the select before the first read would block for 4 second and than the select() before second read() would block for another 5 second - 9 second all together....

Comment: @Charlestone The `select` before the second read would have a 1 second timeout either because only 1 second is left on the read with the least time or because you always use a 1 second timeout because that's your chosen resolution. So it could not block for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what you say you want to do, but it is very ugly.

1. Create a pipe. Close the write end of it. That will give you a descriptor that is dead and useless (for the read end).
2. Take the descriptor for the serial port and `dup` it to save a copy.
3. In your interrupt handler, `dup2` the dead descriptor over the serial port descriptor. This will ensure the next `read` or `write` fails and the function returns.
4. To put things back to normal, `dup2` the saved copy of the serial port descriptor over the one you killed.

Comment: You still don't get me :/. I don't want to interrupt one read. I want to interrupt lets say a function, which consists of multiple reads() (and writes too). When the alarm "buzzes" in the middle of the read() I can track the EINTR ant return error on timeout, but when the alarm "buzzes" when I do not read() I would really like to immediately return error as well.